# Failure to execute tasks by Celery after a month

Tags: redis, celery, supervisord, celery-task, django-celery-beat

My program runs specific tasks daily, these tasks are set by **django-celery-beat**.
Recently, I noticed that the tasks are not performed and all changes are made by resetting the **celery** service configured by **supervisorctl**.

```
command=/opt/taskjo/taskjo-venv/bin/celery -A taskjo worker --pool=gevent --autoscale 4,2 -B  -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler --loglevel=INFO
```

I added these items

```
--pool=gevent --autoscale 4,2
```

New error in log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1224, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: exitcode 0.
```

Recently, I run 4 odoo services on a server with 6 RAM and a large amount of RAM is occupied.

what happened:
**Celery** sends several tasks, but it can't do it, and when it is reset, all the tasks are done.

Do you have a solution?

[WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: exitcode 0 when shutting down worker #273](https://github.com/celery/billiard/issues/273)

[WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 15 (SIGTERM). #6291](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6291)

Comment: Recently, I get an error when restarting :
celery: ERROR (abnormal termination)

RUN -> sudo killall celery && sudo supervisorctl start celery

Comment: Did you check whether your queue has lots of tasks in it? Maybe you have too many tasks in the queue, and your current set of workers can't cope with an increased load?

Comment: I disabled all the tasks and only one of them is active, still there is a problem in execution - the main function of the program is to collect information and send it to users.

Comment: I posted an error and two issues from github, but I don't exactly get an error, but it doesn't do anything, while it has been working without problems for at least a month.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved
Steps to do the work:

1. Checking the server's RAM (it was almost 98% full)
2. Celery configuration (about one gigabyte of RAM was occupied due to the number of workers)
3. Closing a number of services and changing the configuration of Celery

As a result, it has been working without problems for several days.

The following config was replaced:

```
[program:celery]
directory=/opt/taskjo/taskjo
command=/opt/taskjo/taskjo-venv/bin/celery -A taskjo worker -B  -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler --loglevel=INFO

;user=taskjo
;numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/opt/taskjo/logs/celery/worker-access.log
stderr_logfile=/opt/taskjo/logs/celery/worker-error.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=50
stdout_logfile_backups=10
stderr_logfile_backups=10
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; Causes supervisor to send the termination signal (SIGTERM) to the whole process group.
stopasgroup=true

; Set Celery priority higher than default (999)
; so, if rabbitmq is supervised, it will start first.
priority=1000
```